# Obtener de una URL el texto mostrado para parsear en un string

Tags: html, c#, string

Hola Buenas estoy con una duda para poder conseguir lo siguiente:

Lo que quiero hacer es que mi amplicacion C# cuando se ejecute cada X segundos compruebe una URL donde tendre un fichero de texto con datos y esos datos quiero que los parse a un string inicial para su posterior ejecucion segun la accion definida.

Es decir yo tengo estas lineas en el codigo:

```
static class Program { public static string text = ""; // ahora lo que hago es poner yo el string a mano pero quiero que sea bajo peticion web cada X segundos si tiene que cambiar el contenido del string segun lo que muestr el texto de la URL
La URL sera ejemplo http://localhost/text.txt y el contenido quiero que lo aplique en el string, si cambio ese text.txt en la web que cada X segundos o minutos compruebe si tiene que cambiar el string anterior por el nuevo
```

Si me podeis guiar con que puedo hacer en el string seria de buena ayuda y gracias de antemano a todos los expertos en esto.

Comment: Hola, deseas que servidor haga esto; navegar en https://Otroserver/archivo.txt y lo guarde en una varible estática, es muy confuso, puedes poner un ejemplo y un conjunto de pasos para ayudarte con gusto?

Comment: Por pasos seria lo siguiente:
1º Ejecutar la aplicacion y lanza la peticion de string get para traer los datos de texto del web server. (Ahora los tengo que poner yo manualmente en el string de la aplicacion.)
2º cada 5 minutos o 10 minutos que la propia aplicacion haga un refresh del string para comprobar si tiene que traer datos diferentes a los anteriores mostrados.
3º Configuro mi export de datos para que el fichero lo deje en el webserver y asi la aplicacion esta que he creado que recoja los datos mas actualizados.

Creo que me he explicado bien. Espero gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución es para .net 5

```
using System.Threading;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static bool puedeRealizarAccion = true;
    
    public static string text = "";
    
    public static int iteraciones = 5;
    
    public static int segundosDeEspera = 1;
        
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (System.Net.WebClient clienteWeb = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            LeerArchivo();
            
                var proceso =  new Thread(() =>
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while(puedeRealizarAccion && i <= iteraciones)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("#"+i);
                        LeerArchivo();
                        realizarAccion();
                        Thread.Sleep(segundosDeEspera*1000);
                        i++;
                    }
                });
                
                proceso.Start();

        }
    }
    
    public static void realizarAccion()
    {
        // hacer algo con text;
    }
    public static void LeerArchivo()
    {
        using (System.Net.WebClient clienteWeb = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string contenido = clienteWeb.DownloadString("https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt");
                System.Console.WriteLine(contenido);
                if (text!=contenido)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Antiguo valor >" + text);
                    text = contenido;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Nuevo valor > " + text);
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine("___________________________________________________________________");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias me vale de guia tambien para saber como hacerlo. muchas gracias por tu aporte y ayuda

Comment: Si funciona podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta mil gracias.